# MS Sync Framework on Android

Tags: azure, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

We are planning to build sync application on Android using Microsoft Sync Framewrok and Azure Cloud Storage to sync files and folders with Blob and Containers. We have the same application on windows 7 but need one version on Andriod as well.

Any one has idea how to proceed because I am not able to find out any help on web.

Pl share some ideas and sample code if anyone has done the same.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft are developing an API for Azure on Android currently, it can't be far from being released given they updated the iOS toolkit very recently.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/microsoft_blog/archive/2011/05/09/microsoft-announces-windows-azure-toolkits-for-ios-android-and-windows-phone.aspx